# No module named 'irisreader' in Geany

Tags: python, geany

I have installed irisreader module using :

```
pip install irisreader
```

When I run python3 in terminal and import irisreader, it is ok (no error). But, when I run python3 in Geany, there is message : No module named 'irisreader'. I have setted build command in Geany : python3 "%f". But still error.
So, what is wrong with Geany?

I try import irisreader in IDLE. But, still error.

I run MX Linux 21.1 ahs with xfce.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens if you try creating a script that says, for example `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` and running it in Geany? What happens if you try running the same script in the terminal? "When I run python3 in terminal and import irisreader" Does this mean that you run `python3` (no arguments), and then try `import irisreader` at the interpreter prompt? Or does it mean that you put it in a script and try `python3 example.py`? What happens if you try it the other way?

Comment: The result from print(sys.executable) from terminal : /home/mega/miniconda3/bin/python3. The result from Geany : /usr/bin/python3. So, I change in build command with /home/mega/miniconda3/bin/python3. Successfull. Thank you. 
But there is difference between jupyter-lab and Geany when run python script. May be in other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2
pip install your_package

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
pip3 install your_package

# ️ if you get permissions error
sudo pip3 install your_package

# ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable
python -m pip install your_package

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
python3 -m pip install your_package
```

Comment: I have installed it with pip and pip3. Thank you